# Unable to write output

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade

Evening,

I'm trying to run the following command

```
composer show magento/product-community-edition 2.4.* --all | grep -m 1 versions
```

but I am getting an output of the following:

> versions : * 2.4.2
>
> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
> Unable to write output.
>
> show [--all] [--locked] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [-l|--latest] [-o|--outdated] [--ignore IGNORE] [-m|--minor-only] [-D|--direct] [--strict] [-f|--format FORMAT] [--no-dev] [--] [] []

I've had a look at file/folder permissions and set them again

```
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

I've also tried to install the cron again

```
bin/magento cron:install --force
```

But alas nothing helps.

Comment: you got any solution